# Create a list for each object in a json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a json array with:

```
[
  {
    "id":"1",
    "0":"1",
    "name":"Quique",
    "1":"Quique"
  },
  {
    "id":"2",
    "0":"2",
    "name":"Kety",
    "1":"Kety"
  }
]
```

So, I want to get values id and name from the json and use them to represent the json file in with HTML. A perfect result for me will be something like:

```
<div id="container">
  <div>Quique, id 1</div>
  <div>Kety, id 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there a specific error message you're getting?

Comment: I've tried with a for each, but I don't know how to get values inside and append them

Comment: Parse the Json to an array with objects. Then loop through the array and for each object add a div inside the container div and fill this div with the correct information from the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Pure* Javascript solution using `Array.prototype.forEach()` function:

```js
var data = [
  {
    "id":"1",
    "0":"1",
    "name":"Quique",
    "1":"Quique"
  },
  {
    "id":"2",
    "0":"2",
    "name":"Kety",
    "1":"Kety"
  }
],
contentStr = "";

data.forEach(function(o){
    contentStr += "<div>"+ o.name +", id "+ o.id +"</div>";
});
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = contentStr;
```

```html
<div id="container"> 
</div>
```

---

Another alternative would be using `Array.prototype.reduce()` function:

```
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = data.reduce(function(h, o){
  return h + "<div>"+ o.name +", id "+ o.id +"</div>";
}, '');
```

Comment: Skip the temp string using `reduce`: `document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = data.reduce( (html, item) => html + \`<div>${item.name}, id ${item.id}</div>\`, '' )`

Comment: @pawel, added as alternative

Answer (score 2):

`jQuery` solution.

```js
var arr = [{
  "id": "1",
  "0": "1",
  "name": "Quique",
  "1": "Quique"
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "0": "2",
  "name": "Kety",
  "1": "Kety"
}];

(function(arr) {
  return arr.forEach(v => $('#container').append('<div>' + v.name + ', ' + 'id: ' + v.id + '</div>'));
})(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

</div>
```

**Pure** `JS`.

```js
var arr = [{
  "id": "1",
  "0": "1",
  "name": "Quique",
  "1": "Quique"
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "0": "2",
  "name": "Kety",
  "1": "Kety"
}];

(function(arr) {
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var node = document.createElement("div");  
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(arr[i].name + ', id: ' + arr[i].id); 
  node.appendChild(textnode);    
  document.getElementById("container").appendChild(node); 
}
})(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Comment: Modifying the DOM inside a loop is not the best approach when working with large sets of data. You should build a String along the way, and when the loop is done, insert it in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [
  {
    "id":"1",
    "0":"1",
    "name":"Quique",
    "1":"Quique"
  },
  {
    "id":"2",
    "0":"2",
    "name":"Kety",
    "1":"Kety"
  }
];

function div(o) {
  var d = document.createElement('div');
  d.textContent = o.name + " id " + o.id;
  return d;
}

function generate(arr) {
  var wrapper = document.getElementById("container");
  arr.forEach(function(o) {
    wrapper.appendChild(div(o));
  });
}

generate(arr);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example.

```js
var data = [
  {
    "id":"1",
    "0":"1",
    "name":"Quique",
    "1":"Quique"
  },
  {
    "id":"2",
    "0":"2",
    "name":"Kety",
    "1":"Kety"
  }
]

var root = document.getElementById('container');

for( var key in data ){
  element = '<div>' + data[key].name + ', id: ' + data[key].id + '</div>';
  root.innerHTML += element;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```